# C++ use Stored Procedure to return results

Tags: c++, stored-procedures

For the past couple years, I've been maintaining a large C++ application (v100) that utilizes some form of non-ADO database connections, but it works great.

During this time, getting a resultset from the database is quite simple.  I instantiate the return class, with the database object, then Open a query.

```
CUpdates cUpdates(GetDatabase());
CString strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Updates";
cUpdates.Open(-1, strQuery);
```

Just that simple, cUpdates is filled with records.

NOW however, we want to execute a stored procedure, and return the results from it.  But no matter what I try, even changing 'EXEC' to 'CALL', the call fails.  Is there a similar simple method for executing a stored procedure, and returning the results, without having to totally rewrite how the application handles the database connection and returning of data?

```
        strQuery.Format("EXEC dbo.[GetUpdates_ComputerName] '%s', %d, %d", GetWorkstationName(), m_bRetainUpdates, m_bScheduleUpdate);
        cUpdates.Open(-1, strQuery);  //FAILS ON EXEC
```

(I have tested the EXEC statement in SSMS, and it works fine)

We do also use another sql command, for strictly executing statements, but I see no way of returning data with it. Maybe there is a similar command I don't know of?

```
GetDatabase()->ExecuteSQL(strQuery);
```

note:  for the record, I am C# developer (since 1.0 beta).  My only experience in c++ has been learning on the fly over the past 2 years, occasionally maintaining a few of our massive systems.

Comment: Look at the docs for the database API you're using. Not much else we can say without knowing what that is.

Comment: CString.Format will not protect you from SQL Injection vulnerabilities/errors - look at your API for its parameterization features as well.

Comment: "docs for the database API you're using"....HILARIOUS.  The original developer of this massive system retired 2 years ago.  He wasn't a fan of documenting anything.

Comment: The only thing I see that identifies what is being used, is "afxdb.h", which appears to be a Microsoft Foundation Classes C++ Library.

Comment: It seems to be trying to open a CRecordset.

Comment: You are currently in a no-win situation and nothing good will come from you meddling with something you seem to barely understand. You really should consider hiring a C++ developer that knows how to identify and address the types of issues you are facing and has sufficient background doing so effectively.

Comment: It would seem that CRecordset cannot handle an EXEC statement inside of it.  So we converted the new stored procedure to a Tabular Function, so I can use a SELECT instead... which works properly. (though we'd rather use the stored procedure)

Captain Oblivious, You must be a real joy to work with......  I was hired for my C# development skills for the greater 80% of the company code.  The ability for me to read, mostly understand and be able to update/modify c++ code has been a bonus for my employer.  Hiring a c++ developer to do tiny amounts of coding I do in c++, would be a waste of money

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that CRecordset cannot handle an EXEC statement inside of it. So we converted the new stored procedure to a Tabular Function, so I can use a SELECT instead... which works properly. (though I'd rather use the stored procedure)